# Python(Django) how to sort a list of objects by timestamp attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of objects 'posts' that I create with this python function, and I need to sort this list by timestamp attribute.

```
def following(request):
    posts=[]
    follows=Follow.objects.all()
    for follow in follows:
        if follow.follower==request.user:
            posts_user=Post.objects.filter(user=follow.user)
            for post in posts_user:
                posts.append(post)
        
    
    return render(request, "network/following.html",{
        "posts":posts
    })
```

If this was a QuerySet, I would have sorted by using this function:

```
posts = posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()
```

But this is a list so I cant use this function, it gives me this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

How can I sort this list by the timestamp so that the most recent post is the first?

This is the Post class in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_post")
    text=models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

My idea was to convert the list to a QuerySet, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda post: post.timestamp)

Comment: @IgorDragushhak this is not working, because I think it order the list by timestamp and not by -timestamp, how can I fix? The first post of the list should be the most recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__in` [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) to filter your posts and then order that queryset. Something like:

```py
Post.objects.filter(
    user__in=Follow.objects.filter(
        follower=request.user
    ).values_list('user')
).order_by("-timestamp")
```

We first build a queryset to filter all the `Follow` objects where the `follower` is equal to the current user (`request.user`). Next we get all the `Follow.user` objects on all of those filtered `Follow` objects with the call to `values_list`. We pass this queryset to filter `Post` objects where the `user` attribute is inside this queryset. Then we just order by timestamp.

Comment: It gives me this error now: Cannot use QuerySet for "Follow": Use a QuerySet for "User".

Comment: Ok now it works, but I dont undeerstand what means that '.values_list('user'), cau you explain me please? thx